# Multiple CMD ran in docker-compose but did not take effect on the container

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, containers

I have a dockefile that builds a [GoBGP Speaker](https://github.com/osrg/gobgp) image.

Here is the dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        wget \
        iputils-ping \
        traceroute \
        tcpdump \
        iproute2 \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget https://github.com/osrg/gobgp/releases/download/v1.25/gobgp_1.25_linux_amd64.tar.gz && \
    tar zxvf gobgp_1.25_linux_amd64.tar.gz && \
    mv gobgp* /usr/bin/

RUN mkdir -p /opt/gobgp
WORKDIR /opt/gobgp/

COPY docker/gobgp/configs/* ./configs/

CMD ["gobgpd"]
EXPOSE 50051
```

I also have a docker-compose that will bring an entire gobgp network topology. I'm trying to execute multiple commands on the `gobgp_1` service:

```
gobgp_1:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/gobgp/Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "gobgpd -f configs/gobgpd_1.conf ; gobgp global rib add -a ipv4 11.8.0.0/24
               ; gobgp global rib add -a ipv4 11.7.0.0/24
               ; gobgp global rib add -a ipv4 11.6.0.0/24
               ; gobgp global rib add -a ipv4 11.5.0.0/24
               "
    privileged: true
    networks:
      net5:
        ipv4_address: 11.8.0.2
      net6:
        ipv4_address: 11.7.0.2
      net7:
        ipv4_address: 11.6.0.3
      net8:
        ipv4_address: 11.5.0.3
```

The `gobgpd -f configs/gobgpd_1.conf` command ran successfully, but the rest of the command run, but it did not take effect on the `gobgpd` application. If I run the commands manually by jumping into the container bash, the command runs successfully, and I see the change on the `gobgpd` application.

To give you some context of what I am expecting When I should see some information when I use the following command:
`gobgp global rib`
But I don't see anything after bringing the docker-compose up. Otherwise, If I manually run When I run the commands, I see the expected information.

Here is my entire docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'

services:
  isp_1:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/gobgp/Dockerfile
    command: "gobgpd -f configs/isp_1.conf"
    privileged: true
    networks:
      net1:
        ipv4_address: 9.0.0.3
  isp_2:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/gobgp/Dockerfile
    command: "gobgpd -f configs/isp_2.conf"
    privileged: true
    networks:
      net2:
        ipv4_address: 8.0.0.3
  gobgp_5:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/gobgp/Dockerfile
    command: "gobgpd -f configs/gobgpd_5.conf"
    privileged: true
    networks:
      net2:
        ipv4_address: 8.0.0.2
      net4:
        ipv4_address: 11.10.0.3
  gobgp_4:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/gobgp/Dockerfile
    command: "gobgpd -f configs/gobgpd_4.conf"
    privileged: true
    networks:
      net1:
        ipv4_address: 9.0.0.2
      net3:
        ipv4_address: 11.0.0.3
  gobgp_3:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/gobgp/Dockerfile
    command: "gobgpd -f configs/gobgpd_3.conf"
    privileged: true
    networks:
      net4:
        ipv4_address: 11.10.0.2
      net6:
        ipv4_address: 11.7.0.3
  gobgp_2:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/gobgp/Dockerfile
    command: "gobgpd -f configs/gobgpd_2.conf"
    privileged: true
    networks:
      net3:
        ipv4_address: 11.0.0.2
      net5:
        ipv4_address: 11.8.0.3
  gobgp_1:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/gobgp/Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "gobgpd -f configs/gobgpd_1.conf ; gobgp global rib add -a ipv4 11.8.0.0/24
               ; gobgp global rib add -a ipv4 11.7.0.0/24
               ; gobgp global rib add -a ipv4 11.6.0.0/24
               ; gobgp global rib add -a ipv4 11.5.0.0/24
               "
    privileged: true
    networks:
      net5:
        ipv4_address: 11.8.0.2
      net6:
        ipv4_address: 11.7.0.2
      net7:
        ipv4_address: 11.6.0.3
      net8:
        ipv4_address: 11.5.0.3
  server_1:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/gobgp/Dockerfile
    privileged: true
    networks:
      net7:
        ipv4_address: 11.6.0.2
  controller_1:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/gobgp/Dockerfile
    privileged: true
    networks:
      net8:
        ipv4_address: 11.5.0.2
networks:
  net1:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 9.0.0.0/24
  net2:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 8.0.0.0/24
  net3:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 11.0.0.0/24
  net4:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 11.10.0.0/24
  net5:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 11.8.0.0/24
  net6:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 11.7.0.0/24
  net7:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 11.6.0.0/24
  net8:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 11.5.0.0/24
```

Answer (score 0):

GoBGP is just a bgp daemon and itself does not contain any functionality to modify routing table [osrg/gobgp#1493](https://github.com/osrg/gobgp/issues/1493)

If you like to use GoBGP as a component of software router and do packet forwarding, you need to implement that
There are two options to achieve FIB manipulation with GoBGP
Use built-in zebra integration
Write your own code using gRPC API

example using zebra

```
[global.config]
  as = 2
  router-id = "172.17.0.3"

[zebra]
    [zebra.config]
        enabled = true
        url = "unix:/var/run/quagga/zserv.api"
        redistribute-route-type-list = ["connect"]
        version = 2
```